# List of objects in SQL-Server using R

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I want to get a list of all the objects on my SQL-Server using R.

I use this code below to import the object "store", but now I want a list with all objects in order to document it...

```r
Butik <- sqlQuery(db_conn, "SELECT * FROM dbo.store")
```

Comment: `DBI::dbListTables(db_conn)` will give you all tables/views,  including many system tables/views that may make it difficult to extract just user tables. `dbGetQuery(db_conn, "select * from information_schema.tables where table_type='BASE TABLE'")` will give all table names, no views or system tables (the use of `information_schema.*` is discouraged by some, there are better *albeit more verbose* methods).

Comment: BTW, those are using `DBI` with the `odbc` driver package, not using `RODBC` as I suspect you are using. I believe `RODBC::sqlTables` should work for the first, and `sqlQuery(...)` should work for the second.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31521908/3358272

Comment: Perfect, many thanks!